# How to calculate the number of edges in a polygon using PIL/numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

[image]

**Question**

Given a black/white polygon, what is the most efficient method of calculating the number of edges?

For example, the above image should return a value of `7`.

Comment: The most efficient method is to do some of your own research.

Comment: I think this is far too broad/vague, and off topic. See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the number of edges, you can use contour approximation. The idea is that a curve can be approximated by a *series of short line segments*. This leads to a resulting approximated curve that consists of a subset of points defined by the original curve.

Here's a solution using OpenCV. Contour approximation is already implemented as [`cv2.approxPolyDP`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp) which approximates a polygonal curve. The length of the returned value will be the number of edges of the polygon.

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and perform contour approximation
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.03 * peri, True)
    print(len(approx))
```

Result

```
7
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the usage of OpenCV?

Comment: @termlim Not sure what the objection to OpenCV is, but `scikit-image` has similar functionality https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_polygon.html Also, consider using PNG format rather than JPEG for intermediate files when image processing. JPEG changes the values in your images and introduces artefacts and loses information.